# Server-side password protection on parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, hosting

Is it possible to password protect html files from the server side on the public parse.com hosting?

I'd like to have a protected area for a javascript based backend configuration page.

If so, how is this done? I've looked all over to find a way to do it and cannot find it.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse.com hosting doesn't directly offer a server-side access control system. However there is a simple way to do this that is supported, installing express allows the use of basic authentication. This is properly documented in the parse.com docs.

Comment: Here are a couple blog articles of interest. http://blog.parse.com/announcements/building-parse-web-apps-with-the-express-web-framework/  http://blog.parse.com/learn/using-node-js-with-parse/